# Sublime 3 HTML Build Linux

Tags: html, sublimetext, sublimetext3, linux-mint

I'm trying to do a custom build for Sublime 3 so that it opens chromium and the .html document that I'm working on. I'm able to launch Chromium with this:

```
"shell_cmd": "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
```

How do I also open the file I'm working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `$file` [build system variable](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#build-system-variables) to refer to the full path of the current file:

```
"shell_cmd": "/usr/bin/chromium-browser $file"
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me while adding $file_name.

Answer (score 0):

On linux:

```
{
    "cmd": ["google-chrome", "$file"]
}
```

Save your file as ViewInChrome.sublime-build (path is selected as ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User by default, if not select this path)